# How do I set the background image of a pane in JavaFX?

Tags: java, image, javafx, background, pane

I tried giving the pane a background image through SceneBuilder CSS but that simply didn't work.

```
File NavImg = new File("Navigation.png");
Image NavigationImage = new Image(NavImg.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
BackgroundImage NavigationBack = new BackgroundImage(NavigationImage, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
Navigation.setBackground(new Background(NavigationBack));
```

Now I tried this code but it doesn't work either, what do I do?

Navigation is correctly selected in the Controller class. It being the fx:id of the Pane I want to change the background image.

```
@FXML
private Pane Navigation;
```

Comment: First, please use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). This will both make it (much) easier for Java programmers to read your code, and enable the syntax highlighting on SO to work correctly. Second, can you explain what "doesn't work" means here? Post any exceptions you get. Are you sure that the file exists? Where are you executing this code?

Comment: Also how big is that `Pane`? If it's size is `0` the background will not be displayed.

Comment: No errors, exceptions or warnings. It doesn't work in the sense that the image doesn't appear. Yes the file exists in the src/sample folder of the project in which sample.fxml, Controller.java and Main.java also exist.

Comment: That doesn't mean that the relative path `Navigation.png` is correct. What does `NavImg.exists()` return? BTW: the prefered way of referencing resources is using resources on the classpath with `Class.getResource` or `ClassLoader.getResource`.

Comment: The size is 79 by 196. NavImg.exists() returns false. How do I give the correct path?

Comment: Okay I fixed it, I had to add the full path to the file instead of the relative path. Thank you a lot! :D